# Display tool tips only over certain fields

Tags: jquery, sparklines

I have bullet sparkline in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MicheleC/SRyhH/2/) which uses these configurations:

```
$('#sparkline')
    .sparkline(myvalues, {
    type: 'bullet',
    width: 100,
    targetColor: "#000",
    targetWidth: 4,
    tooltipValueLookups: {
        fields: {
            p: 'Current'
        }
    }
});
```

I would like to be able to show the tooltip only over the performance field (and not on top of the target). Is that possible?

Comment: Please clarify, what it the "performance field" and what is the "target"?  It's not clear even in the fiddle

Comment: @Coulton I thought was self explanatory. Performance is the tiny bar and target is the marker. some example in [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullet_graph)

Comment: Well, you thought wrong I think :)

Comment: knowing a bullet chart it's **very** clear what performance and target are

Comment: Therefore it's not self explanatory - existing knowledge is required.  Thanks for confirming.

Comment: of course is required! That's obvious... I'm asking a question about `sparklines` (there is tag for that, just above), so, I assume, only people knowing it could be able to answer (or question) this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the 'Target' tooltip always contains a certain string, like 'Target' as it does in your fiddle, you can amend the `sparkline.js` file to behave how you want it to.

I have changed the following line in the `sparkline.js` file, from:

```
if (!content) {
```

to check for the word 'Target', like so:

```
if (!content || (content.indexOf("Target") != -1)) {
```

Please note I have changed the `External Resources` to point to a file on my server, which I will leave temporarily available.

If you check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MicheleC/SRyhH/2/), it shows it working.
I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I meant. `Target` is the default label for the marker, just because is (in general) in a bullet chart it actually is a value you want to check the others (the `perfomance) against, so the name `target` I guess. You can see in my question that `tooltipValueLookups` changes only `performance` to `current`.